# How to setup multiple Kafka JDBC sink connectors for a single topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to stream data from a particular Kafka topic into two distinct databases (MySQL and SQL Server). Every stream of data should be sent into both tables in both databases. What configuration is required in sink connectors in order to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two JDBC Sink connectors, using the same source topic. They'll function independently, and each send the messages from the specified topic to the target RDBMSs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Robin. When I tried to do it, the one of the two connectors was taken down unexpectedly. How can this be explained?